# convert pandas Series of numpy matricies to Multiindex Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multi-index

I have a pandas series of numpy matricies.

```
data = [[['a','b','c'],[6,3,4]],[['d','e','f'],[2,9,4]],[['g','h','i'],[9,6,4]]]
s = pd.Series(data = data)
s
Out[39]: 
0    [[a, b, c], [6, 3, 4]]
1    [[d, e, f], [2, 9, 4]]
2    [[g, h, i], [9, 6, 4]]
```

I want to convert it to a multiindexed series.

```
sf
Out[47]: 
0  a    6
   b    3
   c    4
1  d    2
   e    9
   f    4
2  g    9
   h    6
   i    4
dtype: int64

sf.index
Out[48]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is unnest list + `set_index`

```
v=s.apply(pd.Series)
m=list(map(len,v[0]))

pd.DataFrame({'v1':v[0].sum(),'v2':v[1].sum()},index=v.index.repeat(m)).set_index('v1',append=True).v2
Out[142]: 
  v1    
0 a    6
  b    3
  c    4
1 d    2
  e    9
  f    4
2 g    9
  h    6
  i    4
```

Comment: woah, I'm having difficulty understanding line 3 (but thanks!)

Comment: @Selah sum with list of list will create one flatten list , repeat here is to create your index , for example 1 repeat 3 will be equal to [1,1,1]